# Change iframe source from another iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Ok, I have 2 iframes inside a parent page (for whatever reason).

I have a navigation menu on parent page, which changes the source of iframe #1...

iFrame #1's job, is to display ANOTHER navigation menu... Like a subnavigation menu...

Now, how can I upon clicking an li inside iFrame #1, change the source of iframe #2? They're both on the same parent page...

Aside from failing miserably, I also get a warning from Chrome's Dev tools -

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/website/index.html from frame with URL file:///C:/website/news/navigator.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Here's some code to make things slightly clearer:

The HTML

```
<!-- HTML for the parent page itself -->
<iframe id="frameone" src=""></iframe>
<iframe id="frametwo" src=""></iframe>
<button onclick="onenav('test.html')">Change 1st frame</button>

<!-- The following is the HTML that is loaded inside "frameone" -->
<button onclick="twonav('test2.html')">Change 2nd frame</button>

// Javascript
var one = document.getElementById('frameone');
var two = document.getElementById('frametwo');

function onenav(x){
    one.src = x;
}

function twonav(y){
    two.src = y;
}
```

To me, this makes sense, since this is all being executed on the parent page... On loading, I query the dev tools and I can see that both, 'one' and 'two' have frame elements... The first button works, the second one, doesn't...

Comment: how did you try in the first place? only the parent can change the content so you will have to communicate from frame1 to parent and parent to frame 2.

Comment: I've amended the op to provide ya'll with a sample... I thought of making a jsfiddle, but then didn't feel like going through the headaches of iframe contents... Don't even know if you CAN code a page and have it run inside a frame inside jsfiddle... Lol...

Comment: If the pages are all from same domain, iframe can go directly via the parent object parent.frames[1]....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works for me when using parent.twonav

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/WH4ns/)

```
var links = [
    'javascript:\'<button onclick="parent.twonav(1)">Change 2nd frame</button>\'',
    'javascript:\'Hello\''
];
var one, two;
window.onload=function() {
  one = document.getElementById('frameone');
  two = document.getElementById('frametwo');
}  

function onenav(idx) {
    one.src=links[idx];
}  

function twonav(idx) {
    two.src=links[idx];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you got it working... Gimme a couple of minutes to pour over this and understand what's different...

Comment: Technically, this is the right solution... It didn't work out for me, but I suspect thats because of a lot of contextual issues with my implementation... Thanks anyways...

Comment: @Abhishek - can you post a url, perhaps I can fix it?

Comment: @Abhishek If confidential, contact me via plungjan.name

Comment: Ah crap... The test files that I was using have gone up and died on me... It'll take me a little while to arrange for new ones... Will you feel just as generous the following day? :-p

Answer (score 0):

How did you try to change the iframe source?

```
parent.document.getElementById('2').src = "the new url";
```

Did you try something like this? I assumed from your message that the id of the 2nd iframe is 2.

Comment: The parent, iframe #1 and iFrame #2 all are linked to a single js file... In this js file, I have created 2 variables for both the frames... Then there's a function, which takes a passed variable x from the element that calls the function, and puts that as the source... so effectively, the html reads like <button onclick="nav('test.html')">, and the js reads like function nav(x){ frametwo.src = x;}... Should work logically, makes no sense to me...