# How do I link different child html in a single parent html from a second child html?

Tags: iframe, hyperlink, parent

First, I am a new at webpage programming and I didn't seem to find a similar question to address the situation I am trying to figure out.  Maybe I wasn't using the right terminology...

I have a parent html file (House.html) with essentially two iframes displayed ("room" and "info"), see below.

```
House.html<br>
-iframe "room"<br>
-iframe "info"

iframe "room"<br>
-Room.html<br>
-->link "link_A"<br>
-->link "link_B"<br>

iframe "info"<br>
-A.html (some text)<br>
-B.html (some text)<br>
```

Within the "room" iframe I am loading Room.html where there are multiple links contained (link_A and link_B).  Clicking a link (link_A) is supposed to change "info" iframe to show A.html.  Again, clicking link_B is supposed to change "info" iframe to show B.html.  All html pages are on the same domain.

I understand how to link a child to a parent, but I am trying to figure out how to display different html pages in a specific iframe within a parent html page from a third html page.

Can anyone point me to an answer?  Would I need to use an if() function in House.html and a target value from link_A or link_B?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change iframe source from another iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166357/change-iframe-source-from-another-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

From http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/qt/target-links-iframes-and-frames.htm

> When you create a document to be inside an IFRAME, any links in that frame will automatically open in that same frame. But with the target attribute on the link (the A element or AREA element) you can decide where your links should open.
>   You can choose to give your iframes a unique name with the id attribute and then point your links at that frame with the ID as the value of the target attribute.

For your specific example, it would look something like:

```
<a href="A.html" target="info">Page A</a>
<a href="B.html" target="info">Page B</a>
```

Comment: "...any links in that frame will automatically open in that same frame..." If I am in the room.html file and it contains code: `<a href="A.html" target="info">Page A</a>` and `<a href="B.html" target="info">Page B</a>` Then how does house.html know which html file to display within the frame code: `<iframe name="info" id="info" src="default.html"></iframe>` Do I need to change the link in room.html to.. `<a href="house.html" src="A.html" target="info">Page A</a>`

Comment: House.html doesn't really care - it's just there to set up the two frames, and load them with the initial pages (room->room.html, info->a.html")

If any page in your site has target="info", then it will replace the info frame (which currently has a.html) with whatever is in the href value of that link.

I think you want to change the link in room.html to
    <a href="a.html" target="info">Page A</a>
Just like I wrote in the example.  Please try it and see if it accomplishes your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to change the src attribute of the second iframe. You can do that with jQuery - e.g. put this code into iframe1 (untested).

```
$('a').click( function() { 
  $('#iframe2', window.top.document).attr('src', 'new-src.html'); 
});
```

Note that the parent page and the frames need to come from the same domain and subdomain (due to the single origin policy). If that's not the case, you would probably need to reload the whole page, by putting `target="_top"` in the link inside the iframe, and changing the src on the server side.