# Javascript/HTML about frames

Tags: javascript, html, frames

I have a page with 3 frames and I want to push a button in the second frame that will send control to the third frame. Then in the third frame a password will be requested and if it is given correctly the user will be able to continue in the page.
My problem is that when I open the page the password on the third frame is requested automatically. How can I make it so that the password will be asked only if I press the button on the second frame?

Comment: Check out the new HTML5 `postMessage` function. That sounds like what you're after.

Comment: i want the third frame to be blank and when the button is pushed and the password is given correctly to reveal it's content. My problem is that it's content is visible even before the password is requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a lot of details missing to get a clear answer, however, sounds like the password page is a "Page" and not a domain prompt? so why not load a "staging" page in the 3rd frame, and then when the user clicks the button in the 2nd frame, load the correct page which requires a password.

are all the frames in the domain? 
are we talking HTML? 
must you use frames?

so when the button is clicked in frame two, you'll want to set the third frames src attribute to the new page. you can get to it using it's ID

[FrameID].src = 'some page'

however, you wont be able to have 2 different domains talk to each other..

i.e. if you have frame 2 from www.domain2.com, and in frame 3 you have www.domain3.com you wont be able to do that..

but if they're all on the same domain (www.domain2.com), it wont be a problem..

UPDATE:
you may have to do parent.[FRAMENAME].src = 'location'

similiar post:

[Change iframe source from another iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166357/change-iframe-source-from-another-iframe)

Comment: How can I do that? I mean press a button that will load a new page in another frame?

Comment: @System - Yes. you can change the framesource on another frame. you can do [framename].src = 'YOUR NEW PAGE' (where framename is the ID of the frame)

Comment: yes they are all on the same domain. I tried requesting the password on the second frame and if given correctly use [FrameID].src = 'some page' but it doesn't change my third frame into another frame.